# Data standardization in the MARS algorithm

Tags: regression, mars

I want to use MARS algorithm. But my dataset consists of 48 data. In Friedman(1991) article, I saw the lower limit as 50. Do you think there is any harm in my application? Do you know of studies with less data? Secondly, something came to my mind. Do I need to standardize the data between 0-1 for the MARS algorithm?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This seems very similar https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/19019/6193

Comment: A post should focus on just one question.  Since the first question seems to be a duplicate (ht to @frank), maybe edit this question to just the second one (which is also the title question)?

Comment: Is there a reason you think MARS might fail or perform poorly with unscaled data?

Comment: Hello, It made sense to combine it in one question, but I will reduce it to one.  I read somewhere that it is necessary in some regression variants, so I was wondering.  I'm still very new to data science, some things can be difficult for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

**No, standardizing the variables is not necessary**, though it is commonly done for convenience and interpretability.

---

#### Description of MARS Model

Given $\bf x$, a p-dimensional vector of input variables, then a MARS algorithm models a response variable $y$ as a linear combination of *basis functions*
$$y = a_0 + \sum_{m=1}^M a_mB_m({\bf x}) + \epsilon,$$
where $\epsilon$ is (usually) a mean zero Gaussian residual, and the basis functions $B_m({\bf x})$ take the form
$$B_m({\bf x}) = \prod_{i=1}^p(s_{im}[t_{im} - x_i]_+)^{u_{im}}.$$
This basis function is a type of multivariate spline where

- $[\cdot ]_+ = \max(\cdot, 0)$ is the *rectified linear unit* (ReLU),
- $s_{im} \in \{-1, +1\}$ is called a *sign*,
- $t_{im}$ is called a *knot* and should lie somewhere in the domain of $x_i$,
- and $u_{im} \in \{0, 1\}$ selects which variables are "activated" in each basis function. In most variations of the MARS algorithm, only a handful of $u_{im}$ terms are allowed to be $1$ for each $m$. This constraint can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^p u_{im} \leq J_\text{max}.$

#### Equivalence of Standardized Models

Given a MARS model for inputs $x_i$, we can show that for any linear rescaling of the inputs, denoted $\tilde{x}_i$, there is another MARS model which is equivalent.

Suppose that each input $x_i$ has a domain $[c_i, d_i]$ and consider a any particular basis function $B_m({\bf x})$ and it's corresponding coefficient. If we standardize $\tilde{x}_i = (x_i-c_i)/(d_i-c_i)$ so that $\tilde{x}_i \in (0, 1)$ then we can also define
$$\begin{aligned}
\tilde{t}_i &= (t_{im}-c_i)/(d_i-c_i) \\
\tilde{a}_m &= \left(\prod_{i=1}^p(d_i-c_i)^{u_{im}}\right)a_m.
\end{aligned}$$
Now it is easy to see that
$$\begin{aligned}
\tilde{a}_m\tilde{B}_m({\bf x}) &= \left(\prod_{i=1}^p(d_i-c_i)^{u_{im}}\right)a_m\prod_{i=1}^p\left(s_{im}\left[\frac{t_{im}-c_i}{d_i-c_i} - \frac{x_i-c_i}{d_i-c_i} \right]_+^{u_{im}}\right) \\
&= \left(\prod_{i=1}^p(d_i-c_i)^{u_{im}}\right)a_m\prod_{i=1}^p(d_i-c_i)^{-u_{im}}\left(s_{im}\left[t_{im}-x_i \right]_+^{u_{im}}\right) \\
&= \left(\prod_{i=1}^p(d_i-c_i)^{u_{im}}\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^p(d_i-c_i)^{-u_{im}}\right)a_m\prod_{i=1}^p\left(s_{im}\left[t_{im}-x_i \right]_+^{u_{im}}\right) \\
&= a_mB_m({\bf x}).
\end{aligned}$$

---

#### Practical note:

With such a small data set, I would encourage you to consider using a Bayesian version of MARS, which is

1. less prone to overfitting and
2. may (more easily) capture uncertainty in the model fit

Depending on the number of inputs, the noise level, and the mean function of the underlying data-generating mechanisim, you may have limited success. But it's certainly worth trying!

If you work with R or Python, I highly recommend the BASS package, which is an efficient and modern implementation of Bayesian MARS. With this package, you do not have to scale the inputs (this will be handled internally).

Some links:

- [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BASS/index.html)
- [Python package](https://github.com/lanl/pyBASS)
- [BASS paper](https://www.osti.gov/pages/servlets/purl/1835765)