# Adding Input Variables

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, predictor

My goal is to predict taxi demand in NYC depending on location and time. I have a dataset with ~18 million observations. 
With that said, I could add a large number of predictors.

But when would I run into the curse of dimensionality.
E.g. adding dummies for all tracts in NYC, would result in 2165 (n-1) additional predictors.

Comment: With 18 million data points, practically speaking you need not worry about having too many predictors.  BTW, I do not understand the tracts comment.  What do you mean by n?  Is 2165 the number of tracts?  Why would you multiply the number of tracts by n?

Comment: Thank you for your input Joel.
There are 2166 tracts in NYC. Adding them to my model through dummies would lead to 2165 additional predictors.

Comment: That number of variables should be fine, given your sample size.  See a related discussion here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10079/rules-of-thumb-for-minimum-sample-size-for-multiple-regression