# sample size calculation for generalized least squares regression

Tags: multiple-regression, sample-size, statistical-power, generalized-least-squares

I want to calculate the sample size for a multiple linear regression with correlated residuals, specifically using generalized least squares. For OLS, it appears that there a various different rules of thumb recommendations and similarly, there are more specific formulae. For example, this is an excellent question and associated answers [multiple regression sample size](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10079/rules-of-thumb-for-minimum-sample-size-for-multiple-regression).

Is there an equivalent set of recommendations or resources for GLS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you estimate the effective sample size (ESS) per subject you can use a univariate (e.g., $t$-test) sample size calculation and divide the sample size by ESS.  An elegant paper showing how to compute ESS for some generalized least squares models is [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/tast.2009.08196).

Comment: @Frank_Harrell - If this example has 132 observations from a single time series (1 individual or source), does this work in the same way? So, ESS=(n-(n-2)Rho))/(1+Rho), if Rho = 0.3, n=132(?), so ESS = 71.53846? Then if we want to detect an effect of beta=0.5 in the gls regression, what do we then use to calculate the univariate sample size calc as the number of individuals is 1 with 130 observations?

Comment: I am not versed on sample size calculations for regular time series.  If you are trying to make inference to individuals in general your sample size is 1 and you can't do any inference.